# Image size change(zoom) moves other images

Tags: css

[My customer's site](http://bda.ctuproject.com/products-designs.html).

As you go over images they get bigger and thats what I want but they push each other. I don't want them to push each other as they get bigger. How can I fix it?

As seen in my link, there is a list of images; one being larger than the rest.  When one image is hovered over, the rest of the images are shifted.  How can I allow one of these images to be magnified without the rest of the images moving?

Comment: Please expand that tiny URL and paste your code here.

Comment: I dont want my customer to find out that I ask question here. And all code I use to get it bigger can be seen from view-source so no need me to share it here

Comment: If you are so afraid of being found out that you're asking questions here as to put up a temporary link and refuse to share your code, perhaps you should not be asking in the first place. We generally do not play well with questions like this as they're often too localized and useless to everybody else. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code

Comment: I think you should to post source code here and remove the tiny url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the padding (or margin) on every image except the "bigger" image to equal the difference between the big image and the small image.  Then, when you hover over an image, remove the margin/padding and apply that to the new image being hovered over.

Simply put, the big image is x pixels bigger than the rest.  Ever other image is its size + x pixels to take up the same size in the layout.  When you hover over another element, the extra space (padding/margin) is stripped and it becomes the larger size.